# Using Group Theory to Solve this IMO problem

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, contest-math, parity

A few weeks ago, I found a fascinating solution to a USAMO combinatorics problem that used group theory. [Look at the 2nd solution on this link to view it.](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2008_USAMO_Problems/Problem_6)

I think there might be a way to use group theory to solve the following IMO problem from 2007:

> In a mathematical competition some competitors are friends. Friendship is always mutual. Call a group of competitors a clique if each two of them are friends. (In particular, any group of fewer than two competitors is a clique.) The number of members of a clique is called its size. Given that, in this competition, the largest size of a clique is even, prove that the competitors can be arranged in two rooms such that the largest size of a clique contained in one room is the same as the largest size of a clique contained in the other room.

I'm relatively new to group theory, so although I've spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem, I can't find the solution. How can it be solved?

If you know of any similar problems that use group theory to produce an interesting proof for a combinatorics problem, you may post that as well. I'm trying to learn how to solve problems this way, and any other examples will help me understand the technique.

Comment: The problem with the group theory solution to the USAMO problem is that it shows that _if_ a solution exists, _then_ the number of solutions is a power of two. Here we want to show that a solution exists at all, so it might be difficult to try to apply the same sort of argument. I have not looked into it in detail, though, so I might be wrong.